# In Perl, how can I ensure that a string corresponds to a valid date?

Tags: perl, time, calendar

I was wondering if there is a simple way in Perl to ensure that a date string corresponds to a valid date.

For example, `2012 02 30` is incorrect because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564594

I believe you'll get the answers you seek from the wise monks.

Comment: Do note that those posts are 6 years old.

Comment: Did calendars change that much in 6 years?

Comment: @Benoit You can say that about anything. Did years change that much from 1999 to 2000? It's probably not a big deal (it's not my downvote) and most of the code will probably still work, but it is worth noting.

Comment: Yes, it's true it's been a while since that thread, but I believe that discussion still adds value. If the answers given are now wrong, let me know and I'll delete the answer. Don't want to mislead anyone!

Answer (score 7):

The [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) module will validate dates when creating a new object.

```
$ perl -we 'use DateTime; my $dt; 
    eval { $dt = DateTime->new( 
        year => 2012, 
        month => 2, 
        day => 30);
    }; print "Error: $@" if $@;'
```

`Error: Invalid day of month (day = 30 - month = 2 - year = 2012) at -e line 1`

It also works dynamically on a given `DateTime` object:

```
$dt->set(day => 30);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this using Class::Date should work

perl testit.pl
Range check on date or time failed

```
use Class::Date;


my $d=Class::Date->new('2021-02-30');
unless ( $d->error ) {
  print "good date\n";
} else {
   print $d->errstr(). "\n";
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the use of [`POSIX mktime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX#mktime), but apparently only if you have a flexible-enough implementation of `mktime`.

What I do is plug the numbers in and then use local time to get them back and if I get the same day value back, it's a valid number. So, given your string:

```
my ( $y, $m, $d ) = split ' ', $date_string;
die "$date_string is not a valid date!" 
    unless ( $d == ( localtime mktime( 0, 0, 0, $d, $m - 1, $y - 1900 ))[3] )
    ;
```

See, in the versions of `mktime` that I'm used to, `mktime( 0, 0, 0, 30, 1, 112 )` would make `'2012-03-01'` and `30 != 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Time::Local](http://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aLocal):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Carp qw( croak );
use Time::Local qw( timegm );

my @to_check = ('1927 06 18', '2012 02 30');

for my $date ( @to_check ) {
    printf "'%s' is %s\n", $date, check_date($date) ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
}

sub check_date {
    my ($date) = @_;

    my ($year, $month, $mday) = split ' ', $date;

    my $ret;

    eval {
        $ret = timegm(0, 0, 0, $mday, $month - 1, $year - 1900);
    };

    return $ret && $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help too:

```
use Time::Piece; #in perl CORE distro since 5.10
use 5.010;
say Time::Piece->strptime("2011-02-29","%Y-%m-%d")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
#2011-03-01
say Time::Piece->strptime("2012-02-29","%Y-%m-%d")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
#2012-02-29
```